# ASP.NET MVC iTextSharp, is it possible to dynamically generate PDF File in code-behind?

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, model-view-controller, itext

So I am currently using iTextSharp to generate PDF Form Document and so far the way I've been doing it is

1. Create Word Document and Export to PDF. Then use software such as Adobe Acrobat Reader to add Form Textbox into it and give property or ID to the Text box for example "#StudentName"
2. After that, in the code-behind I would do something like this

   ```
   keyValues.Add("#StudentName", "Dwight Schrute");
   ```

   Which would add the "Dwight Schrute" value into that textbox when the PDF Document is being generated.

So far my method is working since the Template is Fixed, what I mean is that I know how many Text box is gonna be in the form/document and can place the position or set the properties using Adobe. 
However, now I have to convert a document which originally generated as Excel file into PDF. The problem I am facing now is that, since the number of rows is dynamic and could be let's say 100 rows, then my previous method of Fixed Template and set the Textbox one by one won't work anymore.

Is there a method or way to solve this problem ?

Thanks!

Comment: Please stop using the name iTextSharp. It was replaced by iText for .NET. If you talk about iTextSharp, it is assumed that you are using an old version or a version that was released as a maintenance release (those are made for paying users who can't migrate to the latest version). You can find links to the latest version (7.1.2) [here](https://developers.itextpdf.com/itext7/download-and-install-information/NET), and you should read the [Jump-start tutorial](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial-net/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial-net-version) before asking questions.

Comment: In [chapter 1 of this tutorial for new iText users](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial/sharp/chapter-1-introducing-basic-building-blocks), there an example in which we convert a CSV file to PDF. I know that XLS isn't exactly the same as CSV, but the principle is the same: you have rows and columns of data, and you take that data to create a `Table` with `Cell` objects.

Comment: It's trivial to create a pdf with tables of arbitrary size using itext. It also is easy to add such tables to existing documents unless you expect some reflow of other page components. But what makes you stress the code-behind? You can add arbitrary code to our call it from code-behind...